# How to add JS .sort to Vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following Vue method that I need to add JS `.sort()` to in order to order output alphabetically. I learned JS backward learning framework first and am struggling to understand how I need to make this work JS-wise:

```
filteredByCat (cat) {
  return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
    return element.cat === cat.name
  })
},
```

Somehow I need something like this:

```
filteredByCat (cat) {
  return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
    return (element.cat === cat.name).sort()
  })
},
```

Comment: You should learn the basics of Javascript values, functions, and arrays.

Comment: @SLaks I agree, working on that. Frameworks/libraries made more sense and I needed to know them for my job so I learned a little backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the filtered array:

```
filteredByCat (cat) {
  return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
    return (element.cat === cat.name);
  }).sort();
},
```

---

From the [MDN Documentation for Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example):

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

This means the above example will sort the filtered `businesses` array as strings in alphabetical and ascending order.

If you need to sort an array of objects by a property (say `name`), you need to provide a callback function as a parameter which provides the sort logic:

```
filteredByCat (cat) {
  return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
    return (element.cat === cat.name);
  }).sort((a, b) => { // based off an example in the MDN Documentation for .sort()
    var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); 
    var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); 
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    } else if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

the sort function requires a callback like

```
.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b })
```

Comment: No, the callback parameter is optional. By default, the `sort()` method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order. Try `["B", "A", "D", "C"].sort()` in your console.